# blueimp Basic Plugin: Not uploading in IE, all versions

Tags: file-upload, blueimp

I am using the blueimp fileupload basic plugin in my project. It all works well in Safari, Firefox, Chrome but there is a problem with Internet Explorer 9 and below:

The start callback gets called and in the network tab of developer tools I see the ajax call being executed. However the file is never being upload (I checked on the server, too) and the call eventually ends up in a 408 request timeout.

Any hints on what could be the reason?

Here are my relevant code parts:

```
<input class="input-file" id="fileupload" name="files[]" data-url="/app_dev.php/backend/ajax/upload/wish/1850cf918a43d42" type="file">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/uploader/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/uploader/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/uploader/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        dropZone: null,

        start: function (e, data){
            console.log('start'); //fires in all browsers = fine
        },

        progress: function (e, data){
            console.log('progress'); //fires in Safari, FF, Chrome = fine
        },

        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log('done'); //never getting here in IE cause file doesn't get uploaded.
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem fixed!

There were two issues. One had to do with local network settings.

The other was to implement the correct handling of content type negotiation. See https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup for more details.

Comment: Hi sprain, would you please explain a bit more about local network settings.... i am having same issue, IE is not uploading image....

Comment: I was using a virtual Windows environment on my Mac and had some strange internet connectivity issues there which I could not clearly comprehend. Probably nothing that will every affect anybody else ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just my 5 ¢:
I had a very hard time trying to make it work with pretty links! Following dumps were totally empty!

```
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

So:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'http://code.dev/products/postUpload' // <--- remove trailing slash!!!
});
```